# npm @types packages unusable in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, npm, visual-studio-2017

TypeScript's type packages nowadays reside in node packages of the form `@types/packagename`.

Visual Studio, in general supporting npm packages, can't seem to find any of them:

[image]

In fact that line creates this in the solution explorer:

[image]

It's as if Visual Studio can't even parse the package name properly.

Consequently, it also can't install the package.

This is from the new Visual Studio 2017, and I already know this from Visual Studio 2015.

I have, however, read other people talk about using npm with Visual Studio in a manner than implies they use those type packages.

I'm using a freshly created nodejs console app from the wizard.

So what's going on here and what can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install those packages with the node.js interactive console

```
.npm [YOUR_VS_PROJECT_NAME] install @types/jquery
```

Please note that the dot at the beginning is necessary if you use VS' node.js console. Same with the brackets around YOUR_VS_PROJECT_NAME.

After that it display correctly in the list

But the whole npm integration seems buggy. I'm unable to use the install GUI or, in package.json, sometimes VS is unable to find the available versions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the latest `npm` - the one that comes with VS2015 (and lives under `$(DevEnvDir)\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External` is old (1.4.9). One common issue when you've installed a newer `npm` is that Visual Studio is still using the old one. Assuming the newer one is in your `PATH`, you can fix this under Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->External Web Tools by moving `$(PATH)` up above the built-in tools path like so:
[image: picture of Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->External Web Tools settings dialog]

Comment: notice: In VS2017 it can be found under Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Web Package Management->External Web Tools